# How to show date inRange in floating filter in ag grid react?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to show inRange filter in floating filter instead of showing up in click filter icon in ag grid react.
please refer to image below.

**What I want:**

[image]

**How it is currently showing:**

[image]

```
Ag grid version
    "ag-grid-community": "27.3.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "27.3.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "27.3.0",
```

I tried making filter option only as range but its not working and it is disabling input field in date filter.

```
colDefs=[{
 field: 'date',
 headerName: 'Date',
 filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
 cellRenderer: (data) => {
  return moment(data.value).format(data.dateFormat);
 },
 width: 189,
 minWidth: 189,

 filterParams: {
  suppressAndOrCondition: true,
  filterOptions: [
    "inRange"
  ],}}]

  <AgGridReact
    columnDefs={colDefs}
    rowSelection={rowSelection}
    pagination={pagination}
    paginationPageSize={paginationSize}
    cacheBlockSize={paginationSize}
    suppressRowClickSelection={true}
    rowModelType="serverSide"
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    serverSideStoreType={"partial"}/>
```

[image]